# nVIDIA Driver load error on Xubuntu "can't change power state from D3cold to D0"

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

I have an HP ZBook Fury G8 17,3" FHD IPS i7-11800H 128GB/2TB SSD T1200 4A698EA. On the second SSD Windows 10 Pro is installed. Windows can use my T1200 nvidia card without problems.

On a fresh installed Xubuntu 21.10 5.13.0-27-generic with latest update I have the problem that the nvidia driver doesn't load.

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers list
nvidia-driver-470, (kernel modules provided by linux- 
modules-nvidia-470-generic)
nvidia-driver-495, (kernel modules provided by linux- 
modules-nvidia-495-generic)
nvidia-driver-460-server, (kernel modules provided by 
linux-modules-nvidia-460-server-generic)
nvidia-driver-470-server, (kernel modules provided by 
linux-modules-nvidia-470-server-generic)
```

---

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

or

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470
```

or

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-495
```

installs the software without error.

```
reboot
```

leads to an 100% core load with a process that tried modprobe with no success. At the end nvidia driver wasn't loaded.

```
sudo dmesg | grep -i D3cold
```

gives me

```
nvidia 0000:01:00.0: can't change power state from 
D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible) vgaarb: changed 
VGA decodes: olddecodes=none,decodes=none:owns=none 
nvidia probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -1 
nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major 
device number 507  Nvlink Core is being initialized, 
major device number 507
```

In my opinion there have been some changes in how power management works.
In BIOS I can only choose Hybrid Graphics or UHD, no Power-Mode.
I chose Hybrid Graphics, because in the other case nvidia controller is not visible. That new power management didn't allow to power on some devices (not only graphics) from within a kernel module. There must be another way to do it (in Windows it works). I think the nvidia driver didn't recognize the situation.

Comment: Same issue here. Did you already find a solution?

Comment: Follow this link, there is the same question answered.

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-linux-driver-load-error-cant-change-power-state-from-d3cold-to-d0/202037

Answer (score 0):

I know how to solve this problem: You just have to install a HP-made special ubuntu version from an iso file, then you'll be able to use `nvidia-smi` without any problem:

https://support.hp.com/hk-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-zbook-studio-15.6-inch-g8-mobile-workstation-pc/2100677682

(You'll have to select Linux, Ubuntu as the system you want to use)

> I think this is a trick made by HP, they want to control you from using nvidia driver for free.