# Failure to dual boot my dell latitude 7390 2-in-1 i5 8gen laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, dell

Please I have dual booting on my dell latitude 7390 2-in-1 i5 8gen laptop. When ever i try booting to ubuntu this error
message comes "cant change power state from D3cold to D0" ( config space inaccessible). So I would like to know if anyone here can help me with this issue.

Comment: Please post the entire error message. Is this about Nvidia like https://askubuntu.com/q/1390258/1004020 ? You could try installing the correct version of the Nvidia driver: https://askubuntu.com/q/1258904/1004020